# R - Radio buttons in Shiny don't work anymore

Tags: html, r, shiny

They used to work in an older version of shiny (around 2014). Now I'm getting a mess on the screen. The console is also complaining about input of 0. The graphs aren't printing anymore either (hopefully related to the radios). The calculations they use still works though:

```
    <div id="yaxis" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container"> 
<label class="control-label" for="yaxis">y-axis bounds</label> <div class="shiny-options-group"> 
<div class="radio"> <label> <input type="radio" name="yaxis" value="variable" checked="checked"/> 
<span>Variable</span> </label> </div> <div class="radio"> <label> <input type="radio" name="yaxis" value="default"/> 
<span>Preset</span> </label> </div> </div> </div>


This is what it looks like:
    fluidRow(
       column(3,        
        helpText("Hello!"
        ),  
        tags$div(title="Stock price for output is the midpoint of the slider: 'Stock price visible range'.", 
           tableOutput("outputs")
        ),

        tags$div(title="Select how the y-axis should behave.",
        gsub("label class=\"radio\"", "label class=\"radio inline\"",radioButtons("yaxis", "y-axis bounds", 
             list("Variable" = "variable", "Preset" = "default" ))
        ))
))
```

Thank you!

Comment: The code is trying to change the radioButton class to `radio inline`. Is it possible that you are missing the relevant CSS style file? If you remove the `gsub` part and keep only `radioButtons` part, see if it works.

Comment: That fixed it thank you so much! If you post your answer I'll mark it as the accepted solution.